# Viewing "tree" on a mac in Django without seeing virtualenv tree

Tags: django, tree

I have an older django project in django 1.11 on a mac.  When I use the "tree" command to view the file structure in the terminal, it shows all the typical django files, but also hundreds of lines of virtualenv files.  Is there a way to view the "tree" structure without viewing the virtualenv part?

Answer (score 1):

Check `man tree`.

Try `tree yourfolder -I yourvirtualenv` folder. Probably you can omit `yourfolder` depending on your folder structure.

You can also keep the virtualenv folders outside the projects tree, like inside `~/virtualenvs`.

Comment: The tree -I yourvirtualenv did the trick.  Thank you very much!